# How to avoid renaming all imports

Tags: python, import

I'm trying to use some open source code found on Git. The problem is many files import others modules based on the assumption that all of them are in the root folder. But I created another folder called /logic in the root and therefore, import would be now as

```
import logic.whatevermodule
```

what I did in my files (located in the same /logic folder that have been called from start.js, app in Flask).
So all others files still have

```
import whatevermodule
```

what caused an error because it can't find it.

The structure now is:

```
/logic
    /whatevermodule
        moduleA.py
        moduleB.py
    mylogic.py
start.py
```

Start.py calls mylogic.py using import logic
mylogic.py is my file that uses whatevermodule so to use moduleA it should use

```
import logic.whatevermodule.moduleA
```

moduleA.py uses moduleB.py but its import is

```
import whatevermodule.moduleB
```

what causes error.

What would I do to fix it? ( I don't want to rename all 967 occurrences and don't want to move the folder to the root one.)

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand your structure but it seems like a problem solved by doing the correct import inside of an `__init__.py`

Comment: @noslenkwah thanks, let me add the structure description.

Comment: @noslenkwah I added the structure, can you please explain how to use the correct import inside <__init__.py> ? thanks!!

Comment: What file(s) are the failing `import whatevermodules`'s located in?

Comment: Did you had a look at [sys.meta_path()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.meta_path) and especially this: [creating-your-own-importer-in-python](http://www.grulic.org.ar/~mdione/glob/posts/creating-your-own-importer-in-python/)

Comment: @noslenkwah any files inside whatevermodule folder that use import whatevermodule.something

Comment: If the imports are not relative in your submodule the only way I can think of is adding `logic` to your path. `sys.path.append('logic')`. Make sure you have made `whatevermodule` an actual module.

Comment: @noslenkwah thanks, I will try and tell you if it works.